# Why is ank an alias for add_principal in Kerberos?

Tags: kerberos

The only explanation I could find was:

> "ank was the short form of the equivalent command using the deprecated kadmin5 database administrative tool. It has been kept" ([Kerberos V5 System Administrator's Guide](http://web.mit.edu/KERBEROS/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5/doc/krb5-admin/Adding-or-Modifying-Principals.html))

but this still doesn't explain what ank stands for.